# Splitting string in multiple places Python

Tags: python, string, text-extraction

I am trying to get a set of numbers out of a string. The numbers are nestled between characters.

Here is an example: `NC123456Sarah Von Winkle`

- `NC` is the only part of the string that is a guarantee
- `123456` is the number I want to extract
- `Sarah Von Winkle` is the name, it can be anything

So I cannot just split at 'S' and 'C' to try and grab the digits.

#### Code

Nothing tried so far.

#### Problem

I have no idea how to approach this.

How can I split the string to get only the digits in the middle?

Comment: Regex is your friend for something like this https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html

Comment: Good question (context/task + optional code + problem + question) - good answer (at least I tried) ️

Answer (score 1):

You can use Regex for this:

```
import re
s='NC123456Sarah Von Winkle'
m=''.join(re.findall(r'NC(\d+).*',s))
print(int(m))
```

Comment: Why join? Are we supposed to search a repetitive pattern .. and concatenate the found numbers to a single int ?

Comment: While this code snippet may be the solution, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-‌​code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.

Answer (score 1):

You can try `re`, which is the standard library of Python.

```py
import re

sample_string = "NC123456Sarah Von Winkle"
result_digits = re.findall(r"\d+", sample_string, flags=0)
```

Then your result should be `['123456']`. If you want just an integer instead of a string, you can convert it with `int(result_digits[0])`.

Comment: Nice concise regex `\d+`! Can you explain it and the reason for `flags=0` ?

Answer (score 0):

Use the `regex` module :

```
import re
s = "NC123456Sarah Von Winkle"
t = re.findall("[0-9]+",s)
print(t)
```

This will give :

```
['123456']
```

The regular-expression (pattern) is composed of:

- [*character-range*](https://regexone.com/lesson/character_ranges) `[0-9]` will find all occurrences of any digit between 0 to 9 in the string `s`
- [*quantifier*](https://regexone.com/lesson/kleene_operators) `+` indicates, we are searching for at least one occurrence of the pattern before (e.g. `[0-9]`).

Answer (score 0):

To match and *capture* (= extract) the number, you can use a regular-expression.

**TL;DR:** I would recommend `re.match(r'NC(\d+)', s).group(1)` (details in the last section).

### Regex to match a number

To match a number with a minimum length of 1 digit, use the regular-expression (patter) `\d+' for one or many digits, optionally inside a capturing-group as` (\d+)` where:

1. `\d` is a [*character class*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression#Character_classes) (meta-character) for digits (of range 0-9)
2. `+` is a [*quantifier*](https://regexone.com/lesson/kleene_operators) matching if at least one occurrence of preceding pattern was found
3. `(` and `)` form a [*capturing-group*](https://regexone.com/lesson/capturing_groups) of the enclosed sub-regex

Test your regex on [regex101](https://regex101.com/r/86O2Dq/1) or [regexplanet](https://www.regexplanet.com/share/index.html?share=yyyyp2c0f4r) and choose the right flavor/language/engine (here: Python).

In Python use the built-in regex module `re`. Define the regex as *raw-string* like `r'\d+'`.

#### Find to extract only the number or empty list

Either function [`re.findall`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.findall) to find a list of occurrences:

```py
import re

s = 'NC123456Sarah Von Winkle'
pattern = r'\d+'
occurrences = re.findall(pattern, s)

print(occurrences)
```

Prints:

```
['123456']
```

The first number `occurrences[0]` is yours if not empty:

```
if len(occurrences) == 0:
    print('no number found in: ' + s)
else:
    number =  occurrences[0]
```

#### Split to get all parts

Or function [`re.split`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.split) to split the string into parts:

```py
import re

s = 'NC123456Sarah Von Winkle'
pattern = r'(\d+)'
parts = re.split(pattern, s)

print(parts)
```

Prints:

```
['NC', '123456', 'Sarah Von Winkle']
```

Note: without the capture-group (i.e. without parentheses `()`) the output would be just: `['NC', 'Sarah Von Winkle']` (excluding the splitter-pattern)

Here you would get the number in second part `parts[1]` as long as non-number-prefix like "NC" is guaranteed and followed by a number.

#### Extract with a capturing-group

Use the [`group`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.Match.group) function together with a regex containing a *capturing-group*:

```py
import re

s = 'NC123456Sarah Von Winkle'
capture_number_pattern = re.compile(r'NC(\d+)')
extracted = capture_number_pattern.match(s).group(1)

print(extracted)
```

Prints:

```
123456
```

Note: [`re.compile`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re-objects) returns a compiled *pattern*. This can optimize performance when pattern is re-used multiple times and improve readability of the code.

Pay attention: To make your matching robust and defensive test if there is a match, otherwise an error is raised at runtime, see Python shell:

```
>>> extracted = capture_number_pattern.match('NCHelloWorld2022').group(1)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'group'
```

You can test if a match was found or fail-fast if `match is None`:

```
s = 'NCHelloWorld2022'
match = capture_number_pattern.match(s)
if not match:
    print('No number found in:' + s)
else:
    print(match.group(1))
```

prints:

```
No number found in:NC123456Sarah Von Winkle
```